# Cannot GET data from postgres to DataTables using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql, datatables

I am trying to populate the DataTables row using data from Postgres. So far this is my  JavaScript and HTML file. But I am getting an error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". Any suggestions on why the browser is not able to get the file? I am using express in NodeJS.

```js
var express = require('express');
var postgres = require('./postgres')

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

const result = postgres.migration();
console.log(result)

var port = 8000; 
app.listen(port);

console.log('server on' + port);
```

```js
const pg = require('pg');

const cs = 'postgres://postgres:123456@localhost:5432/lsef';

const client = new pg.Client(cs);

client.connect();

const query = {
    text: 'SELECT * FROM profile',
    rowMode: 'array'
};

client.query(query).then(res => {

    const data = res.rows;

    console.log(data);
    return data
    // data.forEach(row => {
    //     console.log(`Id: ${row[0]} Name: ${row[1]} Age: ${row[2]} Contact: ${row[3]}`);
    // })
}).finally(() => {
    client.end()
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" >
    <table border="1px solid black" id="example">
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody style=text-align:center>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#example").DataTable({
                    "ajax":{
                        'url':'getData.js',
                        'type':'POST',                                                
                        "dataSrc":"",
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": 'id'},
                        { "data": "name" },
                        { "data": "email" },
                        { "data": "contact" }
                    ],
                    "pagingType":"full_numbers",
                    "dom" : "fltip",
                    "stateSave":true,
                    "lengthMenu" : [[5,10,15,-1],[5,10,15,'ALL']],
                    "order":[[0,"asc"]],
                });
            });
        </script>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't seem to understand how things work. In you express app you need to define a post route where you quuery db and send data back, something like this `app.post('/api/data', function(req, res){ client.query(query).then(result => { res.json(result.rows); })` You also need to change this `'url':'getData.js'` to `'url':'/api/data'`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. Thanks, you solved my issue!